# Detect standalone mode in Safari iOS

Tags: javascript, safari, ios-standalone-mode

My goal is to add a A2HS (Add To Home Screen) banner to our site but **not** present it if a user is actively in the PWA. I've seen lots of people around the Internet talk about `window.navigator.standalone` but it simply does not work for me. I've added it to my `if` statement as such:

```js
if( isIos() && window.navigator.standalone ){
  //don't show Add To Home Screen banner
} else {
  //show Add To Home Screen banner
}
```

And it makes sense that this doesn't work because when I type `window.navigator.standalone` in the console of Chrome, it says it's `undefined` because it simply doesn't exist. That said, does anyone have a solution on how to detect if a user is IN standalone mode on mobile Safari?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing on an iPhone XS running iOS 13.3.1, it appears that `standalone` is available in two places:

```
window.navigator.standalone
window.clientInformation.standalone
```

I just checked now on a PWA called 'airhorner' on an iPhone, and both standalones are set to `true`.

Here's what the WebInspector shows for the 'airhorner' PWA in standalone mode:

[image]

Here's what webInspector shows for iOS Safari displaying google.com:

[image]

Comment: I just reproduced with the simulator as well. Previously I was using Safari Technology Preview browser with user agent set to iOS iPhone and that didn't work. Now let me figure out why my banner still appears in standalone. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ryan James: Have you found a solution to this problem yet? I am facing the exact same problem.